# Why was the "th" combination chosen for the "th" sound?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Given that the two "th" sounds don't actually sound like a combination of "t" and "h" why was that particular combination selected or become adopted by the majority ?

Comment: @mpP01 Can you give an example? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @Billaire: "Th" as in *the* or "those" Im asking not about the evolution of the sound but rather the mapping of the "sound" to the characters...

Comment: There are similar questions for CH, SH, etc.

Comment: Arabic has both English "th" sounds in two different letters in its alphabet. Coincidence?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "TH" being pronounced as an **interdental fricative** is called *digraph*, which is a "*pair of characters used to write a single* **phoneme**" (a single sound, said in plain words).

**EDIT:** @z7sg and @mP01; I found the historical course of this sound/letter:

> The first one was **Greek** which had θ (Theta) that had it pronounced as a T (a stop). Many languages, Latin included, used "TH" to write the θ for words **loaned** from Greek, but since /tʰ/ and /θ/ were **not** native phonemes in Latin, ‹th› came to be pronounced /t/; so did the other languages (German, etc). *Plus, the "th" was preserved*.
>
> Later, when Greek changed the θ letter sound **from** /tʰ/ **to** /θ/, all the languages that took loan words, changed the sound accordingly which was already written as "th".

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th_%28digraph%29)

Comment: The only modern languages that pronounce "th" as /θ/ are the ones that already have the phoneme /θ/. Looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_fricative), the main languages written in the Latin alphabet with this phoneme seem to be English, Welsh, and Albanian.

Comment: How does this fit in with the use of letters *thorn* and *eth* in English, and their being transcribed as "th" in modern English?

Comment: @PeterShor That is a bit confusing. First, you missed an important language. But second, Welsh does use *th* as an unvoiced /θ/, but it uses *dd* for the voiced /ð/; the thing is, *dd* devoices in certain contexts, so that means it winds up being /θ/ there. The first point, though, is that Spanish has a /θ/ phoneme; it just does not spell it *th*.  It spells it *z* (the name of the letter is homophonic with *theta*) except if an *e* or an *i* follow, in which case it spells the /θ/ with a *c*. Spanish also has /ð/, but it spells it *d*. So these sounds exist; they just are spelled differently.

Comment: @tchrist: Oops. I was correcting the statement "all the languages which did take loan words changed the sound accordingly". I did forget about Spanish. /θ/ is spelled 'th' in English, Welsh, and Albanian; /ð/ is spelled 'th' in English, 'dd' in Welsh, and 'dh' in Albanian. Since most European languages don't have the phoneme /θ/, I would imagine most speakers don't pronounce it even in loan words (many of them can't pronounce 'th' even when speaking English). I don't know what Castilian Spanish speakers do with loan words containing 'th', but I suspect they pronounce them correctly.

Answer (score 23):

The origin of 'th' really has nothing to do with the development of the English language.  It comes directly from the Roman alphabet.

[From Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th_%28digraph%29):

> The digraph ‹th› was introduced in Latin, which used it to transliterate the letter theta ‹Θ, θ› in loans from Greek. Theta was pronounced as an aspirated stop /tʰ/ in Classical and Koine Greek.

It is likely that this combination was chosen by an early scholar while translating Greek and this standard was then generally adopted.  The 'th' digraph can be found, for example, in the writing of [Lucius Livius Andronicus](http://www.forumromanum.org/literature/livius_andronicus/trag.html#aegisthus) (c. 280/260 BC – c. 200 BC).

According to the OED:

> The Greek letter, which corresponds etymologically to Sanskrit ध dh (and so, by Grimm's Law, to Teutonic and English D), was in early inscriptions represented by TH, and was a true aspirate;

Comment: You say "it's likely that it was chosen by an early scholar", can you prove this?

Comment: @Alenanno: I am trying to find some evidence.  I know that the Romans translated Greek writings and therefore needed to create a digraph for theta.  Here is evidence of the 'th' in early Roman use: http://www.forumromanum.org/literature/livius_andronicus/trag.html#aegisthus

Comment: Essentially my argument is that spoken language developed en masse, in evolutionary mode, because everyone could speak.  OTOH early written language was the preserve of a select few.  Of course, while the empire flourished, many Romans were taught to read and write.  I hope someone with real classical knowledge can answer this question properly as I freely admit it is a lot of guesswork on my part.

Answer (score 18):

Let me offer my personal speculation, for what it's worth of course.

But first, I need to introduce a fact well known to students of Old English but that probably needs to be mentioned here.

---

The vast majority of preserved Old English written documents come from *Wessex*.  King Alfred was the most prominent king of the [House of Wessex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Wessex_family_tree) but the whole period between the 6th Century and the Norman invasion is dominated culturally by the Kingdom of Wessex.

The dialect spoken in Wessex and Sussex was West Saxon whilst Mercian was spoken in Mercia, East Anglia and Essex (*including in London*), Northumbrian in Northumbria and Kentish in Kent.

After the Norman invasion, French was ubiquitous but Middle English gradually recovered from London.  That is, with a strong Mercian East Midland background.

---

Now to the point.

The initial English spelling of /θ/ was indeed *th* as in Latin.  My understanding is that the 'þ' (thorn) and 'ð' were introduced in Wessex where they replaced the initial 'th' inherited from Latin, whereas other kingdoms of the Heptarchy were probably immune to this trend (that's what needs more investigation).

Later when the evolution of English was driven from London, the use of 'th' came back into fashion, also probably under the growing influence of Latin (non Latin characters being probably considered less prestigious).

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_language#Conventions_of_modern_editions) has the following to say about 'th':

> **th**: **Represented /θ/ in the earliest texts**
>   but was soon replaced by ‹ð› and ‹þ›.
>   For example, the word meaning
>   "thought" was written ‹mōdgithanc› in
>   a 6th century *Northumbrian* text, but
>   later as ‹mōdgeþanc› in a 10th century
>   *West Saxon* text.

and

> **þ**: An alternate symbol called thorn used instead of ‹ð›. Represents
>   /θ/ and its allophone [ð]. Together
>   with ‹ð› it replaced the earlier ‹d›
>   and ‹th›. **First attested (in
>   definitely dated materials) in the 8th
>   century**. Less common than ‹ð› before
>   Alfred's time, from then onward ‹þ›
>   was used increasingly more frequently
>   than ‹ð› at the beginning of words
>   while its occurrence at the end and in
>   the middle of words was rare. Some
>   modern editions attempt to regularise
>   the variation between ‹þ› and ‹ð› by
>   using only ‹þ›.

**Important Edit**
This update is intended to answer two similar questions (see comments below) which have raised the possibility 
of the letter thorn (and others such as ðæt ‹ð› wynn ‹ƿ›) actually being originated "from the Norse or Saxons".

The *Saxon* origin is right, the *Norse* isn't.  Here is how things came to be.

1. In Roman Britain, texts were written using the Latin alphabet. 
   Which is fair enough since they were Latin texts. 
   This was also the time  when the Christian religion 
   first entered Britain because it had become the Late Roman empire's official religion.
   Greek words including a theta (θ) were already transliterated in Latin using a 'th' digraph.
2. When the Saxons invaded England, they came not only with their language but also with the alphabet that was used to put it in writing: the [runes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_alphabet).  The runic 
   alphabet included such letters as the thorn ᚦ and the wynn ᚹ. It was an alphabet remotely inspired by the Greek alphabet probably passed on by the Etruscan with whom the Saxons were trading.  Only [very few inscriptions of Old English 
   in Runic alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futhorc) have come down to us.
3. These Saxons were pagans and the Catholic church undertook to Christianise them.  As a result of this effort, Latin made its come back in England together with the Latin alphabet.  The texts were mostly Latin but some included Saxon words 
   transliterated in Latin .  However there was no character for the English *th* sound 
   in the Latin alphabet and two different characters were borrowed:

   - the [ðæt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth_%28letter%29) (ð) because this 
     is how the Irish monks had already 
     solved the problem (Ireland had not been invaded by the Saxons and it had never 
     ceased to be catholic, had always used the Latin alphabet and some of its monks 
     were enrolled along with the ones who had 
     sailed over from Rome to Christianise the heathens).
     Since the *th* was similar to a *d*, it was noted as a *d* with a 
     cross-stroke added cutting its top ascender (a common habit also used for other letters).
   - the [thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29) (þ), because that 
     was how it was noted by the Saxons themselves using the Runic alphabet.

   So that these two letters gradually came to be used interchangeably 
   in Old English to note the *th* sound.  Even in the same sentence 
   you could find the same word using either one or the other.
4. In a few decades, the Vikings had managed to kill a significant proportion of 
   the Latin speakers in Britain and only Wessex had been spared thanks to King 
   Ælfred's mix of stength, luck and diplomatic abilities.
   Having secured his kingdom, and now waiting for the Danelaw to fall ripe, 
   this very able king nearly single-handedly managed to rekindle the once vigorous 
   English cultural life.  With one change though: for want of Latin scholars, the 
   majority of texts were now written in *Ænglisc* (which we now term Old English).
   Quite naturally the runic *thorn* and *wynn* along with the Irish *eth* and a few
   other exotic 'letters' were used to write this nascent English literature.
5. That is, until an arrow landed in Harold Godwinson's eye.
   There are however more than a single reason why all the non standard 
   Latin letters fell out of use.

   - Sure the Anglo-Norman scribes had not learned these letters and were 
     reluctant to use them. But they were only writing French anyway.
   - Mercian London rather than Wessex Winchester was now the beacon of cultural 
     and economical life.
   - Latin was not just the ecclesiastical language any more but also the scholarship 
     language.

   In fact it took more than 200 years for the *th* digraph to regain 
   popularity after the Norman conquest.

Here is a last citation from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29) 
regarding this part of the story:

> The modern digraph th began to grow in popularity during the 14th century; at the same time, the shape of thorn grew less distinctive, with the letter losing its ascender (becoming similar in appearance to the old wynn (Ƿ, ƿ), which had fallen out of use by 1300) and, in some hands, such as that of the scribe of the unique mid-15th century manuscript of The Boke of Margery Kempe, ultimately becoming indistinguishable from the letter Y. By this stage th was predominant, however, and the usage of thorn was largely restricted to certain common words and abbreviations. In William Caxton's pioneering printed English, it is rare except in an abbreviated the, written with a thorn and a superscript E

Now why one might be under the impression that the thorn came from Norse is that 
it was used in Old Norse around the same time as Old English and survives 
till today in Icelandic.  It is supposed that the thorn in the Icelandic alphabet 
is also from Runic origin.

influence alone can not be held responsible for the gradual fall out 
of use of the

Comment: Good answer. I was hoping someone would bring up the thorn. On a related note, when you see comical signs like "Ye olde booke shoppe" it should be noted that nobody in Colonial times said "ye" for "the," rather the y is a representation of the thorn.

Comment: I was under the impression thorn was taken from the Norse or Saxons which would make Wessex the wrong place as some sort of initiator in the adoption process. Why didnt some other king from a more appropriate part of England introduce thorn and then th ?

Comment: I second mP01's question on this. I'd be interested to know why it started in Wessex.

Comment: @mP01 and @Marcin. I've added a detailed appendix to my original answer to clarify the use of the thorn in Wessex and its replacement by the *th* digraph.

Answer (score 3):

It's a question of how printing began in Britain.  In written script even late in the middle ages thorn þ (usually) or eth ð was used; "th" was found bot wasn't the most common.

But printing started on the continent and the first English printers bought their typefaces from there.  Since the 'th' pronunciation was rare on the continent (and not seen in Latin which a great many books were written in), there were no typefaces for thorn þ or eth ð, and English printers were forced to use "th".  Since printing produced vastly greater numbers of books and documents than scribes could, the "th" spelling became the most common and replaced the old letters.

"Ye" as in "Ye olde shoppe" came about due to misunderstanding old manuscripts hands which, written quickly often didn't close up the top of thorn so that þ often looked like Y.

Comment: Source for the *ye* origin?  Some chap called Ian has a [different theory](http://www.ianvisits.co.uk/blog/2011/01/08/the-origin-of-ye-in-ye-olde-shoppe/).

Comment: @z7sg: "Well, it looks like a 'y'" isn't that different a theory.  On the other hand it's almost certainly why yogh became translitered as 'z' :-)

Answer (score 2):

Far too many manuscripts from ancient Roman times are lost to know for sure who chose TH to represent θ and why. It wasn't the /θ/ sound we think of now, though.

The reason it was used in the first place was that after the Norman conquest, French became the primary language of the literate, and "th" was the closest that French had to the sound. Nowadays, "t" and "th" are the same in [French](https://archive.org/stream/tablessynoptique00bert#page/12/mode/1up), but a thousand years ago it was still a somewhat different sound and could maybe substitute if you didn't mind sounding foreign. So that was the natural choice to transcribe our words their way, even if it wasn't /θ/, without resorting to weird pagan runes.

In other words, it was because the first scribe decided to do it that way, everyone else followed the same pattern, and it wasn't important enough to ever bother changing.

It won out over the thorn "þ" (later simplified to "y") in Elizabethan times largely due to French being the refined language of the nobility and upper classes, so it was kind of inevitable that it would percolate down to the lower classes, especially when the upper classes drove most of the printing that was unifying English around the country. The "French" commonly spoken in England was more of a branch from medieval French mixed with some Parisian, becoming its own distantly related creole before merging entirely into English, but it was still seen as superior to English long after it was essentially dead. (This is now called Anglo-Norman French, and later Law French. Many current legal terms come from this offshoot of French.)

This is the same reason we have silly grammar myths like "no split infinitives" -- they just can't exist in French, so they *obviously* shouldn't in English. The whys were slowly forgotten, but the rules persisted.

You can still see thorn as "y" in early American colony documents, but by the revolution it had completely disappeared. The Francophilia of many upper class Americans certainly helped there, too.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/tablessynoptique00bert#page/12/mode/1up - eth disappears around 1100 AD in Old French.
AC Gibson, An Introduction to the Pronunciation of English 1980: Present English /θ/ derives from initial and final (including morpheme final) Old English [θ] (think, throat, bath, tooth, earthly, worthless), from Old French [ð] (faith)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: it's more or less a convention (going way back) that an "h" changes the preceding consonant from a plosive into a corresponding fricative.

I.e. you simply loosen up your lips and get "f" (ph) instead of "p," and "th" instead of "t."

Having "th" stand for both "th" and "dh," in my humble opinion, is a historical mishap.